# Jagged edge on plot

Tags: plotting

```
ellipsoidZ[x_, y_, t_] := -Sqrt[t^2/4 - x^2 - y^2] + 1; 
surfaceZ[x_, y_] := Piecewise[{{0.2, 0.3 <= x <= 0.7 && -0.2 <= y <= 0.2}}, 0];    
pp = 24;
mr = 5;
ContourPlot[surfaceZ[x, y] == ellipsoidZ[x, y, 1.9], {x, 0.29, 0.52}, {y, -0.21, 0.21}, ImageSize -> {400, 400}, PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}, ContourStyle -> Red, PlotPoints -> pp, MaxRecursion -> mr, Exclusions -> None]
```

When I magnify this plot I find jagged edges, I think it is related to MaxRecursion? How to modify the code to draw a smooth line?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. I do not see any "jagged edges" with `mr = 5` on v12.1 MacOS. What do you mean by "when I magnify this plot"? Can you attach an image showing the jagged edges?

Comment: Increasing  plotpoints   `pp=100` together with `mr=2` gives smooth contours in v12 Windows!